# SQL Query to sum ids whenever the rows are reverse

Tags: mysql, sql

my_table==>

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b |
| 2 | b | a |
| 3 | b | a |
| 4 | c | d |
| 5 | d | c |
| 6 | x | y |

Expected Output==>

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | a | b |
| 9 | c | d |
| 6 | x | y |

> So the logic is whenever there is col1 and col2 is reversed for previous add the ids!

```
 SELECT t1.id + t2.id AS id_sum, t1.col1, t1.col2
 FROM my_table t1
 JOIN my_table t2 ON t1.col1 = REVERSE(t2.col2) AND t1.col2 = REVERSE(t2.col1)
 WHERE t1.id < t2.id
 ORDER BY id_sum;
```

Comment: sql query store is for MS SQL server, but you tagged the question with mysql. Removed conflicting product tags. Can you pls add the product tag that you actually use?

Comment: What column identifies *previous* row? SQL table is unordered set

Comment: Not with you x,w does not have previous row so why does it appear in the output, also id 3 has not changed from id2 so how do your get 6 in your output.

Comment: REVERSE() reverses the string value (re-types it from the end to beginning), it does not swap the columns values.

Comment: Sorry the question just asks to add ids whenever the col1 and col2 are in vice versa order!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? None of REVERSE, LEAST and GREATEST are SQL standard functions.

Comment: To SUM id's seems very odd... (It's like summing phone numbers, or SSN's.)

Comment: MySQL workbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select sum(id) as id, least(col1, col2) col1, greatest(col1, col2) col2
from mytable t
group by least(col1, col2), greatest(col1, col2)
```

The idea is to take the least/greatest value amongst the two columns, and use that information to group the dataset.

This would produce your expected results for your sample data.

Comment: Here is a fiddle: as you can see, the query produces the results you expect for your sample data: https://dbfiddle.uk/Kfv2L_il

Comment: Ig in my workbench it is not working! Thanks for the fiddle btw!